# Tool to validate HTTP responses?

Tags: http, validation

I'm going to be messing with some stuff at the raw HTTP level during the next few days and I'd like to make sure I'm following the standard as close as possible. Are there any tools out there to validate the HTTP responses that my server puts out to make sure they conform to the specification?

Comment: Conform with respect to what? What kinds of test would such a tool do?

Comment: Basically it'd tell me if there is an invalid or malformed HTTP response sent from my server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Fiddler. I think it has something along those lines. I know it does give alerts when it gets an invalid HTTP response or protocol error. I'm not sure about a best practices analyzer though, but it does support plugins and scripts.

http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Answer (score 2):

[Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) is a good way to test http requests, great for if you are making your own API.

It allows you to specify the  method (GET, POST, PUT...), the body, etc.  And then it gives you the response and flags as invalid if applicable.  Then you can see the response status (200, 404, etc), headers, body, etc.  Postman won't cache the response, so you can be sure that you are getting updated information.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen Fiddler complain about invalid HTTP protocol traffic, so I suppose it's one way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try http://redbot.org/ (which requires that your server is on the public internet).

Answer (score 0):

Postman does not seem to validate headers,
but on the other hand it shows what header is for what purpose.

Neither Postman nor Fiddler caught that I had double "Vary" http header.
But Fiddler at least showed a flag that my ssl certificate is valid.

https://github.com/vfaronov/httpolice looks promising,
it has many checks on http headers that it runs. It requires `python`, best works with `Django` - where it is installed as a middleware. I haven't tested it yet.